# Android UI test performance degrades after running for a while

Tags: android, performance, android-espresso

We're running some android espresso tests on our CI, the tests does nothing fancy but to scroll a listview a couple of times and reports the average FPS. While we tried to make running environment same for each single run(including killing all process between each run and clearing app data), we found the FPS returned kept gradually degrading over time - if we run it 10 times in a row, the average FPS remains 55, but if we run it more, it drops to ~45.
And this only happens to kitkat devices, on lollipop devices, the performance kept pretty stable.

Any thoughts about what happened here? One of our theory being Android system just gets slower overtime, a 'cold start' would give us a higher result.

Comment: Could it be that you're having some memory leaks in the activity you're testing? I had the same problem reported from the QA department and it the end it turned out that we were leaking the activity every time we opened/closed it.

Comment: @Vesko thanks very much for the info... What we found is that when fps drops GC took more time to execute, turns out FPS is really sensitive to pauses from GC, our theory is that the VM might be struggling to deframentation heap as it runs longer and thus causing heavier GC. Curious how did you guys detect activity leak? What we have done here is to register a global call back to increment a counter for all onCreate() and decrement for all onDestroy(), but we were not able to find any leaked activities from that.

Comment: Finding memory leaks is a huge topic itself. Using activity lifecycle methods to find those isn't the right way to go ... if it was there would be no memory leaks in the apps at all :) To start, familiarise yourself with https://eclipse.org/mat/ (don't worry about the Eclipse in the name, it's available as a standalone tool and works good with Android Studio as well)

Comment: Here is a detailed article on how to proceed: http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/hunting-your-leaks-memory-management-in-android-part-2-of-2/

I've built a tool that we use at Square to automatically detect and identify those. I'll open source it soon, that should help identifying problems faster.